# How to build a dynamic menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hey I new using jsf so I want to build a dynamic  menu with items loaded from database but I'm not sure what functions do I need or how to construct the backing bean for the menu. I already have the database create and three tables Rol, User, Rol x User, Items. Also what will be good attributes for the item table??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `Rol` should have `Items` so you need an extra table `ItemsXRol` i would choose this columns for `Item` : `id, label, url, tooltip, father_item, level` something like that, of course you should choose your columns in order to fill your needs.

Then to create the menu dynamically getting the items from the db using **Primefaces** you can use a `MenuModel` object.

```
//MenuBean
 model = new DefaultMenuModel();  

    //First submenu  
    DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");  

    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");  
    item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");  
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");  
    firstSubmenu.addElement(item);  

    model.addElement(firstSubmenu);  

    //Second submenu
    ...
```

And in the .xhtml file you put something like this:

```
<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}"/>
```

But to generate the menu getting values from the database you can use a DAO to get the MenuItems from your entity.

If your menu has a **n-level** format it could become handy a recursive method to generate the `MenuModel` in which you have to iterate over your `Items` to create the 1st level menus and then recursively the childs of each father.

If you want to read more about `MenuModel` go to https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml

Comment: and how to set the **action** insted of the url? I have my menu like this: `<p:menuitem value="Consultar" action="consultas" />` where consultas is the name of a page.

Comment: I think you can add it instead of the url with something like `item.setCommand("#{menuView.save}");` Looh here for further info: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces provide you a programmatic way to dynamically build your menu using `org.primefaces.model.menu.*` classes. Use a `MenuModel` in your managed bean and reference it on your facelet page. Example:

```
public class MenuBean {  

    private MenuModel model;  

    public MenuBean() {
        // Build your menu here
    }

    // Gets and sets
}
```

And on your facelet:

```
<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}"/>
```

Further details:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf